# foreach on result of GetRecords fails but ToList() solves it

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

Can somebody tell me why this:

```
var rows = csv.GetRecords<TEntity>();
foreach (var row in rows)
{
}
```

fails and this:

```
var rows = csv.GetRecords<TEntity>().ToList();
foreach (var row in rows)
{
}
```

Succeeds?

**EDIT**

```
public static IEnumerable<TEntity> GetData<TEntity>(string basePath)
    where TEntity : class
{
    var entityName = typeof(TEntity).Name;
    var fileName = Path.Combine(basePath, $"{entityName}.csv");

    Console.WriteLine($"Reading: {fileName}");

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
        csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
        csv.Configuration.IgnoreReferences = true;
        var rows = csv.GetRecords<TEntity>().ToList();

        return rows;
    }
}

[TestMethod()]
public void GetDataTest()
{
    var rows = DbData.GetData<EP3_RASGEMIDDELDEN>(BasePath);

    foreach (var row in rows)
    {

    }
}
```

Remove the ToList() in the above example and the foreach in the test method fails. The Test method uses an Entity Framework class to receive the data.

Here's part of the data in the .csv file:

```
WAARDE_BEREKEND;WAARDE_AFGEROND;WAARDE_PRESENTATIE;WAARDE_INPUT;WAARDE_RLC;RIO_NUMMER;ADRAS_ID;GEM_ID;UITSLUITEN;USER_INSERT;TIME_INSERT;USER_UPDATE;TIME_UPDATE
6,9620;7;7;7;7;4450;5145;13281;0;;;;
6,8520;7;7;7;7;4450;5154;13282;0;;;;
6,5310;6,50;6,50;6,50;6,50;4450;5171;13283;0;;;;
6,5080;6,50;6,50;6,50;6,50;4450;5180;13284;0;;;;
7,4460;7,50;7,50;7,50;7,50;4450;5186;13285;0;;;;
6,20;6;6;6;6;4459;5127;13287;0;;;;
6,6280;6,50;6,50;6,50;6,50;4459;5136;13288;0;;;;
6,5520;6,50;6,50;6,50;6,50;4442;5145;13290;0;;;;
```

Comment: What is "fails" and what is "Succeeds" in your particular case?

Comment: It fails with 'Null reference exception' in the foreach. There is no code in the foreach, just the brackets.

Comment: The result returned from CsvHelper.GetRecords<T>() is a IEnumerable<T>. I would expect this to fail in the ToList() too but it does not.

Comment: Your new code is very different to your original question. The new code doesn't work because you are disposing of the `CsvReader` (and its stream) before you are finished with it. The `ToList` fixes it, because you effectively read all of the data out of it **before** disposing of it.

Comment: Yep, it makes sense. That's exactly what I missed. The ToList()  makes the result concrete before dispose.